# How to set Null to variables values that don't exist using Beautifolsoup find_next_sibling() method?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a web scraping of a real state site.
I want to take each post's square meters, antiquity, bedrooms, etc.
Then, with the data extracted, I would like to create a data frame.
The first problem was that the data that I wanted was in the next node. I solve the situation like this

```
page = ("https://www.argenprop.com/departamento-alquiler-barrio-palermo-2-ambientes")
page_requests = requests.get(page)
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page_requests.content, "html.parser")
data = []
for i in soup_page.find_all('i', 'icono-superficie_cubierta'):
    data.append(i.find_next_sibling())

lista_data = []
superficie_cubierta = []
for i in data:
    lista_data.append(i.text.strip())
for i in lista_data:
    superficie_cubierta.append(str(i[0])+str(i[1]))
```

My problem is that in some post, there is not a data point for some variables. And, I don't know how I can
set a Null/None value to does post where there is not that data.
I mean, that the length in some variables is 17 and, in the others, it's 20. How can I set Null to that points where I don't have the data

I tried putting an if sentence so, when the condition is true when the element exists, set the number of the variable and, if the condition is false, set None. But I can't understand how to do it

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you tagged it with `dataframe` you could use a `dict` while missing values would be flagged with `NAN`:

```
...
data = []
for i in soup_page.select('.listing__item'):
    d = {'adress':i.h2.get_text(strip=True)}
    f = {
            f.find_previous_sibling('i').get('class')[0].split('icono-')[-1]:
            f.get_text(strip=True) 
            for f in i.select('ul.card__main-features span')
        }
    d.update(f)
    data.append(d)
...
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page = ("https://www.argenprop.com/departamento-alquiler-barrio-palermo-2-ambientes")
page_requests = requests.get(page)
soup_page = BeautifulSoup(page_requests.content, "html.parser")

data = []

for i in soup_page.select('.listing__item'):
    d = {'adress':i.h2.get_text(strip=True)}
    f = {
            f.find_previous_sibling('i').get('class')[0].split('icono-')[-1]:
            f.get_text(strip=True) 
            for f in i.select('ul.card__main-features span')
        }
    d.update(f)
    data.append(d)
pd.DataFrame(data)
```